# Flowplayer with multiple overlays and image buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, flowplayer, overlays

Hi I am having trouble with [flowplayer overlays](http://flowplayer.org/demos/tools/overlay.html). I have multiple over lays with an image button. The overlay is "popping up" but the flowplayer is not loading. Please if you can spot the error in my code it would be most appreciated.

```
<script>

$(function() {

// setup overlay actions to buttons
$("button[rel]").overlay({

    // use the Apple effect for overlay
    effect: 'apple',        

    expose: '#789',             

    onLoad: function(content) {
        // find the player contained inside this overlay and load it
        this.getOverlay().find("a.player").flowplayer(0).load();
    },

    onClose: function(content) {
        $f().unload();
    }
});             

// install flowplayers
$("a.player").flowplayer("http://www.bazookatag.com/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf"); 
}); 
</script>

<p>
<div>
<div style="float:left; width: 400px; height: 325px; padding-left: 20px;">
        <button rel="#overlay1"><img src="images/playersplash.png" width="355" height="301" />
        </button> 
</div> 

    <div style="float:left; width: 500px; height: 325px;"><h2>Stars</h2></div>
    </div> 

<div>
    <div style="float:left; width: 500px; height: 325px; padding-left: 25px;">    <h2>Domed</h2></div>
    <div style="float:right; width: 400px; height: 325px;">
         <button rel="#overlay2"><img src="images/playersplash.png" width="355" height="301" /></button> 
    </div>
    </div>

    <div>
    <div style="float:left; width: 400px; height: 325px; padding-left: 20px;">
    <button rel="#overlay3"><img src="images/playersplash.png" width="355" height="301" /></button> 
</div> 
    <div style="float:left; width: 500px; height: 325px;"><h2>Viral 4</h2></div>
    </div> 

<div>
    <div style="float:left; width: 500px; height: 325px; padding-left: 25px;"><h2>Viral 5</h2></div>
    <div style="float:right; width: 400px; height: 325px;">
        <button rel="#overlay4"><img src="images/playersplash.png" width="355" height="301" /></button> 
    </div>
    </div>
</p>

<!-- overlays for both videos -->
<div class="overlay" id="overlay1">
<a class="player" href="http://pseudo01.hddn.com/vod/demo.flowplayervod/flowplayer-700.flv">
    &nbsp;
</a>
</div>

<div class="overlay" id="overlay2">
<a class="player" href="http://pseudo01.hddn.com/vod/demo.flowplayervod/flowplayer-700.flv">
    &nbsp;
</a>    
</div>

<div class="overlay" id="overlay3">
<a class="player" href="http://pseudo01.hddn.com/vod/demo.flowplayervod/flowplayer-700.flv">
    &nbsp;
</a>
</div>

<div class="overlay" id="overlay4">
<a class="player" href="http://pseudo01.hddn.com/vod/demo.flowplayervod/flowplayer-700.flv">
    &nbsp;
</a>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

install player, before overlay:

```
    // install flowplayers

    $("a.player").flowplayer("http://www.bazookatag.com/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf"); 
    }); 

// setup overlay actions to buttons

    $("button[rel]").overlay({

    // use the Apple effect for overlay
    effect: 'apple',        

    expose: '#789',             

    onLoad: function(content) {
        // find the player contained inside this overlay and load it
        this.getOverlay().find("a.player").flowplayer(0).load();
    },

    onClose: function(content) {
        $f().unload();
    }
});
```